# Scrapy: sending http requests and parse response

Tags: http, scrapy

i have looked at  [scrapy docs](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) , but Can scrapy send http form (Ex: user name , password ,....) and parse the result of sending this form ?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213467/cant-get-through-a-form-with-scrapy is an example

Comment: thanks a lot , I think this meets the purpose

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the same page : http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                      callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

You have just to pass a callback parameter function to the request and then, parse the result in parse_page2 ;)